# Let X and Y be two random real numbers, what is the probability that x = min(x,y)?

Tags: probability, statistics

As the questions suggets I want to find the probability that x= min(x,y) being that x and y are random numbers, my guess is it's 1/2, since x is random and could be greater than x or not, but I'm not sure, could you help me?

Let me elaborate, x and y are two independent random variables with exponential distribution, and z is the minimum of the two of them, the question is what is the probability that z= x.

Comment: This is very vague.  What probability distributions govern $x$ or $y$?

Comment: You can't uniformly "choose a real number", otherwise every choice would have probability $0$. You *can* however use a distribution with support $\mathbb{R}$ and choose $X,Y$ according to that. Then you can calculate $P(X = \min(X,Y))$.

Comment: Let me elaborate, x and y are two independent random variables with exponential distribution, and z is the minimum of the two of them, the question is what is the probability that z= x

Comment: Due to symmetry, $P(X < Y) = P(X = \min(X,Y)) = P(Y = \min(X,Y)) = P(Y < X)$. Since you're using a continious distribution, we can ignore the case when $X=Y$, as it has probability $0$. Since $X < Y$ and $Y < X$ are the only possible events, the sum of their probability is $1$. Now from $P(X < Y)=P(Y < X)$ and $P(X < Y)+P(Y < X)=1$ we can deduce that $P(X < Y)=P(Y < X)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielP That was what I imagined, but couldn't put it in a formal way, I'm guessing this result is true for n exponential independent variables? The probability would be 1/n. Let Z = min(X_1,...,X_n) and we want P(Z=X_i).

Comment: Are these identically distributed?  If so, then yes.  Ties have probability $0$ and each is equally likely to be the minimum.

Comment: To be clear:  saying these variables follow an "exponential distribution" is not enough.  After all, there are infinitely many exponential distributions.  I assume you meant to say that they all follow the *same* exponential distribution.  That and independence are all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the probability that $X < Y$, so generally $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y\, f(x, y)\,dx\,dy$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and distributed exponentially, say $f(x, y) = ab e^{-ax-by}$, $x, y > 0$ you get $a/(a + b)$.

On the other hand if $X$ and $Y$ are simply i.i.d.,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y\, f(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y)f(y)\, dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y)F'(y)\, dy \\
&= 1/2
\end{align}
as you guessed.

Comment: Yes! And the generalization is 
$$\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i} $$
for n independent distinct exponential random variables and P($X_i=min(X_i)$)

Answer (score 0):

Due to independence, the **joint distribution** of $(X,Y)$ is the product of the individuals pdfs:

$$f(x,y)=e^{-\lambda(x+y)}\mathbb{1}_{x>0}\mathbb{1}_{y>0}.$$

What you are looking for is:

$$P(X>Y)=\int_{x>y>0} f(x,y)dxdy \tag{1}$$

Geometrically, (1) means integration over the lower half part of the first quadrant which can be expressed as a certain volume under the surface with equation $z=f(x,y)$, the total volume being $1$.

This volume, due to the symmetry of this surface with respect to line $y=x$ is equal to $1/2$.

[image]

*This picture represents the joint pdf as a surface (in blue) ; I have taken the case $\lambda = 1$ ; it is to be noted that the two marginal distributions are materialized as the trace of this surface onto planes Oxz and Oyz ; the symmetry $x \leftrightarrow y$ is materialized as the symmetry of the surface with respect to vertical plane with equation $y=x$ (in red).*

Comment: Just added a graphical representation.